# Posting cheats/easter eggs

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, allowed-answers, cheats

I think I found a cheat/hack/easter-egg in some game.

Is it OK to post them as my own question and answer? ( http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ )

Or are we disallowed to post tricks/cheats?

Comment: Is it in the multiplayer portion of a game?

Comment: @badp It is applicable to both. But I tested it only in Single Player.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally we're OK with cheating in single player games, so cheat codes, console commands, mods that change the game and make it easier, etc, are generally regarded as OK.  Hacking or cheating in games where there are competitive elements is usually regarded as a bad thing.

Although you can ask and answer your own question, you may want to think about how contrived the question and answer pair may appear to other users.  Did you have a problem to start with, and then solved it with the cheat you discovered?  If so, you're probably OK.

However, if you found a cheat and just want to share it, you might have difficulty making a "good" question that fits the model of the site.  If you think you can make a question to which alternative answers are likely to be good, you're probably OK, but I'd encourage you to look at the FAQ carefully as you write your question to make sure that you don't fall afoul of any of the common close reasons.  You might end up downvoted or even closed if the question just isn't up to snuff!

Comment: Regarding types of cheats/mods in multiplayer - I tend to break them into "cheats for everyone" vs "cheats for a few", for example, a server mod that gives a level low-gravity (for everyone) I find acceptable, vs an auto-aim mod (used to gain an advantage over other players) as not-acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the question by it self is with in the  guidelines of Gaming.SE it is ok to ask it and answer your own question.

With easter eggs it can be a bit blurry if they are ok to ask due to [the FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) stating:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions **based on actual problems that you face**.

But are possible to ask.

Here is an example of [a bad ester egg question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108876/easter-eggs-in-starcraft-ii-hots) for Starcraft 2 HotS and [a good one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/109139/who-are-the-named-prisoners-in-conviction) for same game.

As long as the "cheat" is not in multiplayer where you are hurting others game play experience they should be ok to ask also.